# How to set the background color of part of the text in QTreeWidgetItem?

Tags: python, qt, qtreewidgetitem

For example, the text of QTreeWidgetItem is ["Hello world"], is there any way to set the background color of 'Hello'? The method `setBackground` seems to set the whole column.

Comment: As it is a `QTreeWidget`, you can insert a `QLabel` with "coloured" HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a custom Widget as default view of your QTreeWidgetItem, its easy with QLabel. This is an example with a QListWidget and QListWidgetItem:

```
QListWidgetItem* MainWindow::addColoredItem(const QString& name, const QColor& backcolor, const QColor& textcolor) {
    QListWidgetItem* item = new QTreeWidgetItem(this);
    QLabel* label = new QLabel(this);
    label->setStyleSheet(QString("QLabel{background: %1; color %2;}").arg(backColor.name(), textColor.name()));
    ui->listWidget->addItem(item);
    ui->listWidget->setItemWidget(item, widget);
    return item;
}
```

For QTreeWidgetItem, make the same steps.

Comment: The question is about another thing. Just `label->setText("<SPAN style='background-color: red'>Hello</SPAN> World")`, no widget style sheets.