# Partially coloring text of QTreeWidgetItem

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I am trying to get part of the text of a QTreeWidgetItem to be set to red and have found a few examples, namely [how to set the background color of part of the text in qtreewidgetitem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38866696/how-to-set-the-background-color-of-part-of-the-text-in-qtreewidgetitem) and [is it possible to partially italicize the text of a qtreewidgetitem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533316/is-it-possible-to-partially-italicize-the-text-of-a-qtreewidgetitem), but they are in C++ so I'm not following them. I get that they're both setting the actual color in the text of a QLabel but am not sure how they're then attributing that to the child item of the tree. I've written up example code to help out.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        
        self.tree = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget(Form)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.tree.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.tree.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.tree.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(250, 90))
        self.tree.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(250, 90))        
        self.tree.setObjectName("tree")
        self.tree.header().setVisible(False)
        
        rootItem = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.tree)
        rootItem.setText(0, "I AM ROOT")
        
        tempString = "I AM \033[0;31m CHILD \033[0;0m"
        
        mixedLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        mixedLabel.setText(tempString)
        print(mixedLabel.text())
                
        childItem = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(rootItem)
        self.tree.setItemWidget(childItem, 0, mixedLabel)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I know the QLabel part is working because the print statement gives me

[image: cmd line output]

as I expect, but the actual widget gives me

[image: widget output]

where it is not recognizing the ANSI color command. I think I've set up the `setItemWidget()` call correctly but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QLabel does not support ANSI color commands. You should use Qt's HTML subset (rich text) instead:

```cpp
mixedLabel.setText("I AM <span style='color: red'>CHILD</span>")
```

Documentation for the capabilities of their HTML subset can be found here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/richtext-html-subset.html

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a ton for the help, I'll look into the documentation.